# C# Windows 8 Metro game development

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I've been looking for ways to develop metro style games for Windows 8 in C#. All I can find are tuts explaining how to build games in C++ or JS/HTML5.

I'd really like to continue with C# since I really like the language. What are the recommendations around this topic?

Comment: Do see [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx).

Comment: I'm talking about Metro games. The XNA team has not said anything about supporting metro style development afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd look into [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/), both of which have support for Windows 8 Metro style apps.

I'm not sure what the state of XNA is these days.

Comment: Which one would you recommend and why?

Comment: @MrSoundless I wouldn't as I don't use them. They are also targeting different audiences. MonoGame is after the cross-mobile game developer, SharpDX is after the DirectX developer who can't be bothered with C++. From what I can tell, they are both being well supported so I'd say both are equally viable as reliable Open Source libraries.

Comment: That's a nice and short explanation. Thanks. I've marked this answer as 'accepted'.

Comment: @MrSoundless No problem, sorry I can't recommend any. Hopefully one will work out for you.